Descriptive complexity of analytic continuation
Consider the set of complex power series
$$
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n
$$ that have radius of convergence $1$ and can be analytically continued to the neighborhood of some point on the unit circle. What is the descriptive complexity of this set when viewed as a subset of the Polish space of complex sequences? One can ask similar questions for Dirichlet series
$$
g(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n^s}
$$
A crude estimate of "having radius of convergence $1$" using the radius formula is $\Pi^0_3$. I initially hoped the analytic continuation part might be true analytic, which would add to the examples of naturally occuring non-Borel sets, but then convinced myself that it is actually Borel (but it could still be a good example of statements of high quantifier complexity). To see that it is Borel, first note that for any point $c$ in the open unit disk we can compute $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n(z-c)^n$, the power series expansion of $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ centered at $c$, in a Borel way, because we can compute $f^{(n)}(z)$ easily and then plug in $z=c$. Then $f(z)$ can be analytically continued to some point on the unit circle iff there exists $q>0$ and a sequence $(c_i:i<\omega)$ of points in the open disk with rational coordinates that converges to some point on the boundary (this can be expressed in a Borel way by saying the sequence is Cauchy) and such that the radius of convergence of $f(z)$ centered at $c_i$ is at least $q$. This feels somewhat like $\Sigma^0_4$ but at this point my ability of quantifier counting is overwhelmed...plus there could well be a much simpler way to express this using theorems from complex variables.

In "Then $f(z)$ can be analytically continued to some point on the unit circle iff there exists $q>0$ and a sequence $(c_i:i<\omega)$ of points in the open disk with rational coordinates that converges to some point on the boundary (this can be expressed in a Borel way by saying the sequence is Cauchy) and such that the radius of convergence of $f(z)$ centered at $c_i$ is at least $q$." why do you need the sequence? Isn't a single point with rational coordinates of distance $<q$ from the boundary of the unit circle where the radius of converge is at least $q$ enough (and necessary)?

@WillSawin Yes you are absolutely right. This seems to make the anaytic continuation part rather simple in descriptive set theoretic sense...

For an analytic function given by its power series, existence of an analytic continuation to some open set intersecting the unit circle is $Σ^0_2$.
To see this, for an analytic function, its power series at $z_1$ is uniformly computable from its power series at $z_0$ ($\sum_{n=0}^∞ a_n (z-z_0)^n$), $r>|z_1-z_0|$, and $M≥\sup(|a_n| r^n)$.  And an analytic continuation to a given point (with the function analytic in an open neighborhood) can be decomposed as a finite number of hops recentering the series, so its existence is $Σ^0_2$ (each intermediate $z_i$ can be rational, so we can encode them along with corresponding $r$ and $M$ into an integer, and the condition on each $M$ is $Π^0_1$).
As a side note, by Cauchy's inequality,
$$
\sup(|a_n| r^n) ≤ \sup_{|z-z_0|<r} |f(z)|.
$$
Also, given $M$ and $r$, the power series at $z_0$ is uniformly computably interconvertible with the function encoded (in a standard manner) as a continuous function on $\{z:|z-z_0|<r\}$.
We also have:

Having radius of convergence $>r$ is $Σ^0_2$-complete; it is equivalent to
$$
\exists r_1>r\, \exists M \,∀n \, |a_n|r_1^n≤M.
$$
Having radius of convergence exactly $r$ (including exactly 1) is $Π^0_3$-complete.  To see this, given a $Π^0_3$ formula $∀n ∃m ∀k \, φ(n,m,k)$, for each $n$ we add some terms to the power series that are small enough for distances $<1-1/n$, but large at distance (say) $1-1/(2n)$, one term for each $m'$ such that $∃m<m' \, ∀k \, φ(n,m',k)$ fails.
The conjunction of having an above continuation and having radius of convergence exactly 1 is thus $Π^0_3$, and it is also $Π^0_3$-complete.  To see this, build the power series centered at -1/2, radius of convergence >1/2, and all coefficients nonnegative reals, and such that it blows up at some positive real $z<1$ iff the $Π^0_3$ formula fails (and otherwise it blows up at 1), and then recenter the series at 0.

